# Python: How to use re.search() in a compound if statement (is it even possible?)

Tags: python, regex

I need to see if a line contains 2 numbers, *and* if the first one is less than 0.5:

```
if re.search('((?:\d|[.\-\+]\d|[\+\-]\.\d)[\d\.\-\+e]*)[^\d\.\-\+]+((?:\d|[.\-\+]\d|[\-\+]\.\d)[\d\.\-\+e]*)',foil[ifrom],re.IGNORECASE) and float(re.group(1))<0.5:
    #above is wrong: no such thing as re.group(1)...
elif re.search('((?:\d|[.\-\+]\d|[\+\-]\.\d)[\d\.\-\+e]*)[^\d\.\-\+]+((?:\d|[.\-\+]\d|[\-\+]\.\d)[\d\.\-\+e]*)',foil[midsep+1],re.IGNORECASE) and float(re.group(1))>0.5:
    #also wrong
```

What would be the correct way to do this?  Is it even possible to access the results of the search inside the same "if" statement ?

Comment: Try with the walrus operator.

Comment: Always use a raw string when creating a regexp.

Comment: You need to assign the result of `re.search()` to a variable, and use `variable.group(1)`

Comment: I don't know regex but something looks absolutely like an XY problem here

Answer (score 3):

Use a [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) in Python 3.8+:

```py
if (m := re.search(r'..REGEX HERE...', foil[ifrom], re.I)) and float(m.group(1))<0.5:
    print(m.group(0)) # prints match value
elif:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

The match data object is assigned to `m` and `m.group(1)` access the Group 1 value that is available in the same `if` condition.

A quick test in Python console:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = "20"
>>> if (m := re.search(r'[0-9]+', s)) and int(m.group(0))>5:
...    print(m.group(0))
... else:
...     print("No")
... 
20
>>>
```

Comment: Sweet code... gives me a syntax error of course though.  This is for a Fusion360 add-in, I'm stuck with Python 3.7 only.  This will be a great answer in the future for other people googling this problem though, when 3.8 is more widespread.